# How to make UITextView "Done" button resignFirstResponder?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, ios, uitextview, iboutlet

I am trying to make my editable `UITextView` resign the keyboard (`resignFirstResponder`) when the user taps "Done." Using a `UITextField`, I have been able to do this with the following code:

```
- (IBAction)doneEditing:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

... and then to attach it to the relevant `UITextField` in Interface Builder to the action "Did End on Exit."

However, with a `UITextView`, I can't seem to access the "Did End on Exit" action. Any suggestions on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**new Answer**

On your View, you'd have a UIBarButton ("Done") that is connected to the IBAction below:

```
- (IBAction)doneEditing:(id)sender {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Where textView is your textView outlet defined in your .h file and connected in Storyboard or .xib file. Like this:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
```

**old Answer**

Check the following:

1. Is UITextViewDelegate specified
       in .h
2. Implement delegate method
       for uitextview:
       textViewShouldEndEditing, return YES
3. make sure your .m (controller) is the
       delegate for uitextview in IB
4. resignFirstResponder should now
       work.

Comment: textViewShouldEndEditing is NOT called when the user presses the Return/Done button on a UITextView, checking for carriage return in shouldChangeTextInRange is the only way

Answer (score 91):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. Instead, the following delegate method should be invoked like this:

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]){
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Paste that into the class that you assign to be the UITextView delegate and it'll work.

Comment: This answer would neglect the whole reason for using a UITextView where the user will want to add multiple lines which is what the return button does in the context of a UITextView.

Comment: @zachzurn - I don't think that applies to this use case, where there is a desire to have multiline text and a done button on the keyboard. It's clear to me that having the Done button act like a return button instead would be poor usability.

Comment: If the user copy pastes a carriage-return into the textView this will get triggered.

Comment: Good point Albert - although that only will happen if they paste *solely* a carriage return. If there are any other characters in the paste then it won't trigger. But worth being aware of. Theoretically if you were concerned you could create a custom UITextView and override the paste method, although to me it probably wouldn't be worth the trouble.

Comment: if you listen the \n word to judge if you should disappear the keyword, then you might encounter an awkward situation that you will dismiss keyboard every time you when you input new linke

Answer (score 3):

You can implement `UITextViewDelegate` and wait for "\n", in Swift 4 :

```
    myTextView.delegate = self

// ...

extension MyViewController : UITextViewDelegate {

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "\n" {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

To have the done button dismiss the keyboard and `resignFirstResponder` you have to implement a delegate method.

1. In your .h implement the UITextFieldDelegate

   ```
   @interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
   ```
2. Then implement the textFieldShouldReturn in your .m

   ```
   -(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
   {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
   }
   ```
3. Don't forget to link the delegate of UITextField to the file's Owner (very important)